# svg chrome bug leaves black box when move or remove object

Tags: google-chrome, svg, webkit

i am dynamically creating a html object type that loads an external svg, then appendChild it to the document.  (I'll note it is in a canvas area, though i dont think it matters).  That all works fine.

When I modify the left or top, or just removeChild the object, it leaves behind a black box in the original svg area of it's height and width.  If i am moving the svg it renders in the new location fine, just it is leaving behind a black box in the original loc.

this only happens in chrome.  (no black box in firefox).  reading some of the chrome docs i see they have dealt with some webkit problem in the past leaving a black box.

in the svg file, if i use a viewport, or dont, i get the same bug

anyone seen this before?  is there a work around?  (i must use object, not image)

part of creating the svg...

```
var object2 = document.createElement("object");
object2.setAttribute("type", "image/svg+xml");
object2.setAttribute("data", "bitmaps/whirl.svg");
object2.className += " roomObj3";
object2.style.left=''+(xxx+8)+'px';
object2.style.top=''+(18)+'px';
object2.id="tornado"+xx;
document.getElementById('objLayer').appendChild(object2);
```

moving leaves behind a black box (but also correctly moves)...

```
var id2="tornado"+xx;
ele=document.getElementById(id2);
var xpos=parseInt(ele.style.left);
ele.style.left=""+(xpos+100)+"px";

.roomObj3 {
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try forcing Chrome to use the GPU with:

```
.roomObj3 {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: doesn't help.  Good thought, though.  Interesting to note is the black  area becomes z-index=0, or always was (actual svg with higher z would occlude it).  So, i dont think the black area is getting added to this class.

Comment: try adding it to the parent element (`#objLayer`)?